# opt/lampp/bin/httpd: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypt.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: arch-linux, libraries, xampp

I use Arch Linux (x86_64)

I updated my repositories today with the following command

```
Sudo Packman -Syu
```

But the xampp program no longer runs

```
Stopping all servers...
Restarting all servers...
Starting MySQL Database...

Starting Apache Web Server...
Exit code: 8
Stdout:
apache config test fails, aborting
Stderr:

/opt/lampp/bin/httpd: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypt.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Starting ProFTPD...
Exit code: 8
Stdout:
proftpd config test fails, aborting
Stderr:

/opt/lampp/sbin/proftpd: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypt.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

After a bit of checking I found that the libcrypt.so.1 file exists

Output the command locate  `libcrypt.so.1`

```
[ahmadreza@ahmadreza-sys ~]$ locate libcrypt.so.1
/usr/lib/libcrypt.so.1
```

The version of the files is as follows:

```
[root@ahmadreza-sys lib]# file libcrypto.so.1*
libcrypto.so.1.1: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=4c926b672d97886b123e03a008387aecf0786de4, stripped
[root@ahmadreza-sys lib]#
```

output command `sudo ldconfig -v | grep libcrypt`

```
[ahmadreza@ahmadreza-sys ~]$ sudo ldconfig -v | grep libcrypt
ldconfig: Path `/usr/lib64' given more than once
(from <builtin>:0 and <builtin>:0)
ldconfig: Can't stat /usr/libx32: No such file or directory
    libcrypt.so.2 -> libcrypt.so.2.0.0
    libcrypto.so.1.1 -> libcrypto.so.1.1
    libcryptsetup.so.12 -> libcryptsetup.so.12.7.0
[ahmadreza@ahmadreza-sys ~]$
```

cammand outout `file /opt/lampp/bin/httpd`

```
[ahmadreza@ahmadreza-sys ~]$ file /opt/lampp/bin/httpd 
/opt/lampp/bin/httpd: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=00effd3a02918135bf3106612c2b59866e4f92fe, stripped
[ahmadreza@ahmadreza-sys ~]$
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Is `/usr/lib/libcrypt.so.1` 32 or 64 bit? It's probable that it should also point to /usr/lib/libcrypt.so.1.1 or similar.

Comment: How do I know if it is 64-bit or 32-bit? @Bib

Comment: Run `file /usr/lib/libcrypt.so.1*`.

Comment: I added in the text @Bib

Comment: You have libcrypto.so.1.1, but no libcrypto.so.1. There should be a symlink between those. The `locate` result suggests it should exist, but doesn't. Try running ldconfig, and if it still does not exist, then create a symlink yourself, `ln -s libcrypto.so.1.1 libcrypto.so.1``.

Comment: I did what I did and made a link from the file, but the error remains
```lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Feb 15 18:43 libcrypto.so.1 -> libcrypto.so.1.1```

Comment: Either `/opt/lampp/bin/httpd` is 32 bit, or the `libcrypt.so.1.1` file has been built incorrecly. You did run `ldconfig`? You can also check with `ldconfig -v`.

Comment: Yes I did .... I added the output in the text above @Bib

Comment: Ugh, libcrypt != libcrypto. As you can see you have libcrypt.so.2, not libcrypt.so.1. If that has just been updated, then I would assume all binaries requiring libcrypt.so.1, should also be updated. You may have to install the old libcrypt.so.1 package.

Comment: Did some digging.  libcrypt.so.2 comes from libxcrypt And it looks like a lot of basic tools from pam to ppp can depend on it.  So you want whatever option lets you have both old and new versions installed simultaneously.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had the same error, solved by installing this package "libxcrypt-compat".
It is not in pacman, install via AUR.

```
yay -S libxcrypt-compat
```

Comment: I can not believe it .... It worked ..... Thank you very much for helping me ... I check you as the best answer

Comment: libxcrypt-compat became a split package only 8 days after you posted this solution. New solution is `yay -Syu lib32-libxcrypt-compat`

Answer (score 3):

**libxcrypt-compat is no longer in the AUR, it has become a split package as of 24 Feb 2022.**

This is what you'll need now, from the AUR:

```
yay -Syu lib32-libxcrypt-compat
```

**UPDATE:** The package name ends with "compat" as in "compatibility" not "compact" as in "compressed." I did not misspell the package name, do not edit my post to correct what is not an error. You are spreading misinformation by doing so.

Comment: Strange, as of 2022-08-01, `libxcrypt-compat` seems to work fine for me

Answer (score 3):

after 24th february libxcrypt-compat became available in arch linux core, so it can be installed using pacman

```
sudo pacman -Syu libxcrypt-compat
```

This same package has libxcrypt as a dependency, which is also in the arch core repository.